# Не заполняются поля наследуемого класса

Tags: java, android, cursor, extend

Есть абстрактный класс `Entity`, реализующий конструктор `Entity(Cursor cursor)`, чья единственная задача вызвать абстрактный метод `parse(Cursor cursor)`, который забивает данные из курсора в поля наследуемого объекта.

```
public Entity(Cursor cursor){
    parse(cursor);
}

protected abstract void parse(Cursor cursor);
```

Есть класс Contact, наследуемый от Entity, в нём описан конструктор

```
public Contact(Cursor cursor) {
    super(cursor);
}
```

и описан метод

```
@Override
protected void parse(Cursor cursor) {
    _id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable._ID));
    _name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.NAME));
    _my_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.MY_ID));
    _phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.PHONE));
    _sowa_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.SOWA_ID));
}
```

В классе `Contact` есть метод

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Contact> getAllMap(){
    HashMap<Integer, Contact> contacts = new HashMap<>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", new String[]{"*"}, null, null, null, null, "my_id", null);
    if(cursor != null){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            Contact c = new Contact(cursor);
            contacts.put(c.getMyId(), c);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

Проблема вот в чём: при создании экземпляра класса `Contact` таким образом в классе заполняются все поля типа `Long` и `int`, а поля строковые заполняются пустыми строками, причём дефолтных значений у них нет. Если пошагово дебажить, то поля заполняются нужными значениями, но после выхода из конструктора приходят к описанным выше значениям.

Если же изменить метод `parse` таким образом:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Contact> getAllMap(){
    HashMap<Integer, Contact> contacts = new HashMap<>();
    Cursor cursor = getAllCursor("my_id");
    if(cursor != null){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.parse(cursor);
            contacts.put(c.getMyId(), c);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

То всё работает нормально и поля заполняются как нужно. Мне не понятно такое поведение кода, неужели придётся дублить в каждом наследуемом классе конструктор с вызовом `parse(Cursor cursor)`?

**UPD: Полный код классов**

```
public abstract class Entity {
private static final String TAG = "DEB Entity";
public Entity(){

}

public Entity(Cursor cursor){
    parse(cursor);
}

/**
 * Парсит данные из курсора в объект
 * @param cursor - курсор с данными
 */
protected abstract void parse(Cursor cursor);

/**
 * Возвращает объект таблицы БД соответствующий классу последовательности
 * @param <T> - класс таблицы БД унаследованный от DBTable
 * @return объект таблицы БД
 */
protected abstract <T extends DBTable> T getTableObject();

/**
 * Возвращает набор данных готовых к сохранению/обновлению
 * @return ContentValues набор данных
 */
protected abstract ContentValues getCV();

protected boolean changed = false;
protected long _id = 0;

public long getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    _id = id;
}

public boolean getChanged() {
    return changed;
}

/**
 * Сохраняет объект в БД
 */
public void save(){
    if(getId() == 0){
        insert();
    } else if(changed){
        update();
    }
    changed = false;
}

protected void insert(){
    _id = Statics.sdbr.insert(getTableObject().getTableName(), null, getCV());
}

protected void update(){
    Statics.sdbr.update(getTableObject().getTableName(), getCV(), DBTable._ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(getId())});
}
```

}

```
public class Contact extends Entity {
private static final String TAG = "DEB Contact";

public Contact() {
    super();
}

public Contact(Cursor cursor) {
    super(cursor);
}

private String _name = "";
private String _phone = "";
private int _my_id;
private int _sowa_id = 0;

public String letter = "";

public String getName(){
    return _name;
}

public String getPhone(){
    return _phone;
}

public int getMyId(){
    return _my_id;
}

public void setId(int id){
    if(id != _id) {
        _id = id;
        changed = true;
    }
}

public void setName(String name){
    if(!_name.equals(name)) {
        _name = name;
        changed = true;
    }
}

public void setPhone(String phone){
    if(!_phone.equals(phone)) {
        _phone = phone;
        changed = true;
    }
}

public void setMyId(int my_id){
    if(my_id != _my_id) {
        _my_id = my_id;
        changed = true;
    }
}

public int getSowaId() {
    return _sowa_id;
}

public void setSowaId(int sowa_id) {
    if(sowa_id != _sowa_id) {
        _sowa_id = sowa_id;
        changed = true;
    }
}

private static Cursor getAllCursor(String order_field){
    return Statics.sdbr.query(new ContactTable().getTableName(), new String[]{"*"}, null, null, null, null, order_field, null);
}

@Override
protected <T extends DBTable> T getTableObject() {
    return (T) new ContactTable();
}

@Override
protected ContentValues getCV() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ContactTable.MY_ID, _my_id);
    cv.put(ContactTable.NAME, _name);
    cv.put(ContactTable.PHONE, _phone);
    cv.put(ContactTable.SOWA_ID, _sowa_id);
    return cv;
}

public static ArrayList<Contact> getAll(){
    ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getAllCursor("name");
    if(cursor != null) {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Contact contact = new Contact(cursor);
            Log.d(TAG, contact.getName());
            letters = contact.checkLetter(letters);
            contacts.add(contact);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contacts;
}

public static ArrayList<Contact> getAllLikeName(String filter){
    ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = Statics.sdbr.query(new ContactTable().getTableName(), new String[]{"*"}, "name LIKE '?'", new String[]{"%" + filter + "%"}, null, null, "name", null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Contact contact = new Contact(cursor);
            letters = contact.checkLetter(letters);
            contacts.add(contact);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contacts;
}

/**
 * Проверяет наличие заглавной буквы в массиве букв (для телефонной книги)
 * @param letters - массив букв
 * @return изменённый массив букв... или нет
 */
public ArrayList<String> checkLetter(ArrayList<String> letters){
    String name = getName().trim();
    if(name.length() == 0){
        return letters;
    }
    String letter = String.valueOf(name.charAt(0));
    boolean letterFound = false;
    for(String l: letters){
        if(l.equals(letter)){
            letterFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!letterFound){
        this.letter = letter;
        letters.add(letter);
    }
    return letters;
}

/**
 * Возвращает все контакты с ключами в виде наших ID в телефонной книге
 * @return HashMap<Integer, Contact> - все контакты
 */
public static HashMap<Integer, Contact> getAllMap(){
    HashMap<Integer, Contact> contacts = new HashMap<>();
    Cursor cursor = getAllCursor("my_id");
    if(cursor != null){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            Contact c = new Contact(cursor);
            contacts.put(c.getMyId(), c);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contacts;
}

@Override
protected void parse(Cursor cursor) {
    _id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable._ID));
    _name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.NAME));
    _my_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.MY_ID));
    _phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.PHONE));
    _sowa_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactTable.SOWA_ID));
}
```

}

**UPD 2: Решением такой проблемы может являться создание фабрики**

В класс `Entity` добавил метод `getInstance`:

```
/**
 *
 * @param cls - класс унаследованный от Entity
 * @param cursor - курсор (может быть null)
 * @param <T> класс - класс, унаследованный от Entity
 * @return - объект класса T
 */
public static <T extends Entity> T getInstance(Class<T> cls, Cursor cursor){
    try {
        T instance = cls.newInstance();
        if(cursor != null){
            instance.parse(cursor);
        }
        return instance;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Теперь объект класса `Contact` вместо того, чтобы писать в каждом унаследованном классе конструктор с вызовом ф-ции `parse` можно без проблем получить вот такой функцией:

```
Contact c = Entity.getInstance(Contact.class, cursor);
```

Comment: а в классе Contact есть конструкторы?

Comment: @metalurgus да, 
public Contact(Cursor cursor) {
    super(cursor);
}

Comment: попробуйте в таком случае мой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень плохо вызывать в конструкторе переопределяемые методы, и ваш код - отличный тому пример.
Нужно держать в голове порядок инициализации объекта.

> 1)Статические поля класса Parent
>
> 2)Статический блок инициализации класса Parent;
>
> 3)Статические поля класса Сhild;
>
> 4)Статический блок инициализации класса Child;
>
> 5)Нестатические поля  класса Parent;
>
> 6)Нестатический блок инициализации класса Parent;
>
> 7)Конструктор класса Parent;
>
> 8)Нестатические поля  класса Сhild;
>
> 9)Нестатический блок инициализации класса Сhild;
>
> 10)Конструктор класса Сhild.

В данном примере инициализация нестатических полей наследника перетирает значения, записанные при вызове конструктора родителя.

Comment: В таком случае я не понимаю, почему поля перетираются избирательно? Ведь значения полей типа `int` и `Long` остаются верными. 
И второй вопрос: есть ли возможность избавиться от необходимости каждый раз в конструкторе наследуемого класса писать вызов метода parse(cursor), раз уж вызов его в наследуемом конструкторе - это плохо?

Comment: 1) можете написать имена полей, которые перетираются и которые инициализируются верно? Пока я вижу что корректно должно проставляться поле _id.
2)Избавиться нужно от вызова parse(cursor) в Entity.
Как насчет использования фабрики?

Comment: 1. Ещё верно заполняется _my_id, _sowa_id пока всегда 0, поэтому не проверял. И ещё я писал в посте, что и _phones и _name тоже не null на выходе, они являются строками нулевой длины.
2. Касательно фабрики - хорошая идея, я внёс некоторые изменения в код, добавил метод для создания экземпляра нужного класса, обновил в посте

Comment: По поводу п.1.
Внимательней с порядком инициализации.

В классе Contact вы сами определяете поля.
private String _name = "";
private String _phone = "";
private int _my_id;
private int _sowa_id = 0;

И эта инициализация происходит после вызова конструктора родителя Entity.

В общем мораль проста:. **В конструкторе можно вызывать либо final либо private либо static методы. Иначе есть риск выстрелить себе в ногу.**

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте в `Entity` создать конструктор без параметров

```
public Entity(){
}
```

и во втором конструкторе вызывать сначала первый:

```
public Entity(Cursor cursor){
    this();
    parse(cursor);
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: @НикитаЛещёв, Тогда вам придется показывать полный код обеих классов...

Comment: Добавил полный код обоих классов